# Postman: Access environment variables or read from file

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I'm trying to test an API that needs AWS credentials (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`).
Right now I'm setting them explicitly in the Postman environment, but I need to do this every time I'm refreshing my credentials.
So I'm looking for a way to automatically add these and found Postman pre-request scripts.

Unfortunately there is no `process.env` and also no `fs.readFileSync`(to read `~/.aws/credentials`).
Is there another way to pass information from outside Postman?

Comment: can't you refresh credential from postman ? you cna write a sscript to refresh your token

Answer (score 2):

You could pass those values in with [Newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman):

The `--env-var` flag can be using the resolve placeholder variables in a collection `{{token}}` to the value passed at runtime.

When using Newman from the Command Line

```
newman run collection.json --env-var "token=$TOKEN"
```

When using Newman as a library:

```
const newman = require('newman')

newman.run({
  collection: 'collection.json',
  envVar: [ 
      { "key":"token", "value":`${process.env.TOKEN}`}
  ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, this already helps a lot.
Nevertheless I would still like to have this functionality in the Postman UI when I develop my collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it,

1. Built an API that runs in my machine at port 8080. This GET API endpoint will read my AWS credentials located at `~/.aws/credentials` and will return them as

> { "aws_access_key_id": "", "aws_secret_access_key": "" }

2. Within Postman client tool, I have created collection variables called `key` and `secret`
3. Within collection `Pre-request Script` added this code, purpose of this code is to call API endpoint running on my machine and accept payload response and update collection variables

> ```
> pm.sendRequest({
>     url: "http://localhost:8080/aws/credentials",
>     method: "GET",
>     }, function (_, response) {
>         if (response.status == "OK") {
>             const body = response.json()
>             pm.collectionVariables.set("key", body.aws_access_key_id)
>             pm.collectionVariables.set("secret", body.aws_secret_access_key)
>             return
>         } else {
>             throw new Error(response.text() || "Error fetching aws credentials")
>         }
>     }
> )
> ```

4. My API requests within collection can now use `key` and `secret` variable values to execute followup steps.

---

One drawback I see is each developer in a team has to have this local API endpoint.
I'm interested to know if there is a better way to solve this problem.